# Dynamic creation of TextBox in front of every child node of a TreeView when being expanded

Tags: asp.net, css

How do I dynamically create text box in front of every child node in a TreeView when it's being expanded.

I've created a program, which has some parents nodes and within some child nodes
I want that whenever the user expands any 'parent node' in  TreeView control, I just want to show (textbox/html input) in front of every 'child node'.

PROBLEM: I've created text boxes dynamically on server side, but am unable to place it in the right position (i.e. in front of every child node).

Can it possible through server side code? I.e `textbox1.position 12,12;` or some CSS or HTML?

Comment: Perhaps you can provide some code to start with.

Comment: By the way, you do know that you can simple add a string to the HTML tags created? That way you can add `style="position: relative; left: 10px; top: -5px"`, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the extra controls on the server and then position them using CSS. However, my guess is that you'll want to create them on the client side. That's JS (suggestion: use jQuery). That way your code will be faster and the user experience will improve.

It's easier to give you pointers if you provide information on what you're trying to achieve.

EDIT:

You can add this string to the control when you render it server-side. Note, though, I wouldn't recommend this approach.

```
style="position: relative; left: 10px; top: -5px"
```

Comment: Thnaks alot for response.
but priorily I want to 'create', position' text box using .net code (server side code) . i wana do it without using jquerry or JS

Comment: @user1670504 Using C#, VB? You need to provide more specifics. :)

Comment: using c sharp, i wana write c # code, which help program to position the "control" on the place which i want. i.e label1.position=position.x-10;

Comment: @user1670504 I'm not entirely sure I get your intention. What you describe **is supposed** to be done using CSS (and possibly JavaScript). But you say that you want to solve it using C#. May I ask why? It's doable but won't be recommended because what you'll have to do is to fire an `onclick` event, by that, post the page back to the server, remodel it and send it back. It's slow. It's cumbersome. It's just wrong... Unless you have a really good reason, don't do it. :)

Comment: thanx alot for answer, i just want to do it , because i dont know css and i know c# server side code , thats why i want to position asp page control using c# code

Comment: @user1670504 You're probably not going to like my answer but the best practice is, as I mentioned before, to do all such operations on client-side. That includes (and is pretty much limited to) CSS and JavaScript. I'm a real C#-junkie and I love hard typing and compile time error detection, so I don't like JavaScript. But I don't like crowds and high oil prices neither and still have to live with it. If you're going to develop for web, you're going to have to use CSS and JS. Deal with it. :)

Comment: @CreativeCode Yes, I probably can. However, it's a matter of more work than just a few questions and answers. It's not **that** complicated but it takes a while to get used to. What I'd suggest you to do is to set up a goal, e.g. "create a page with blue text that upon a hover will turn green and upon a click will turn white creating the impression of disappearing". You can do that using a local file, no servers required. Split the goal into smaller goals and see that you know how to do them yourself. If not, ask here. (Share a link with me to such question and I'll help you.)

Comment: Thanks alot , kinldy suggest me some solid books or tutorial from where i can learn client side code, thnaks in anticipation

Comment: @CreativeCode I can only suggest you the things that worked for me. I didn't use any books and tutorials are seldom of right quality and on the right level. I did, as I said before, like this. Imagine a project - your goal (see the example I've given above about the text). Then try to do that. If (when) you get stuck - ask on SO about **that particular moment**. Give me a link to the question. I (or someone else) will help you with **that** issue. After a week or two, you'll be done and have learned a lot. That's the best advice I can offer you.